# WiFi shows 150Mbps but file copy is just 40Mbps

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, smb

I have two wireless routers at home with the same ssid to have better coverage. Both operating at 802.11b/g/n mixed mode. My laptop shows it's connected at 144Mbps 802.11n when close to Technicolor router and file copy from a server share goes at 10MB/s which is about 80Mbps. When I go to another room and wait a bit until it switches itself to Tenda N150 router it shows 150Mbps but copying of the same file now goes at half speed! Around 5MB/s (41Mbps), so what the heck? Laptop is like one meter from this Tenda router.
Weird thing is that copying something from laptop back to server goes 10MB/s! I have tried with another pc on LAN (gigabit) and copying from that to laptop is also just 5MB/s but copying to that pc goes at 10MB/s
Seems like this Tenda router has download speed limited to half of the upload. Any ideas what can it be?

Comment: I think you need to do some research into the basics of WiFi... If your laptop shows "144Mbps" WiFi connection you will be lucky to get 50% of that speed in actuality assuming your network or other device is not bottlenecking somewhere due to WiFi being half-duplex and it's overhead for protocol, error correction, sharing, number of devices connected, etc. It is expected that Superuser users do some basic googling/troubleshooting/researching prior to asking a question, and it appears you have done none of those things as this stuff is pretty much "common knowledge"

Comment: @acejavelin As an actual 802.11 engineer, I find most of the "common knowledge" of 802.11 on the internet to be complete riddled with false myths and absolute BS. For example, you just said he'd be lucky to get 50% of his 802.11n PHY rate, which is BS. It's easy to get TCP throughput of over 70% of an 802.11n PHY rate. 802.11  expected thruput calculations are more certainly complex than wired Ethernet, but the "common knowledge" tends to be BS like "802.11 performance is incalculably crappy, don't even try to calculate it". I don't mind him asking.

Comment: @acejavelin why would this "luck" apply only for one direction of traffic and the other was more lucky?

Comment: I will do some tests using psping and post here...